# Android Intent.ACTION_PICK not closing picker if crop is selected

Tags: android, image, camera, gallery

When I try to select a photo from gallery and I set **crop**, clicking on check-mark will not close dialog and it stays in picker dialog, but if I just remove **intent.putExtra("crop", "true")** it will function properly!:

```
                        val intent = Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
                        intent.type = "image/*"
                        intent.putExtra("crop", "true")
                        intent.putExtra("scale", true)
                        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1)
                        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1)
                        // indicate output X and Y
                        intent.putExtra("return-data", true)
                        intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString())
                        startActivityForResult(
                                Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.select_photo)),
                                REQUETS_SELECT_PICTURE)
```

[image]

Comment: Any error or exception ?

Comment: no error and no exception!

Comment: There are hundreds of gallery implementations pre-installed across the >20,000 Android device models. Your crop extras are undocumented and will be supported by only a fraction of those gallery implementations. Plus, since those crop extras are unsupported, the results you will get may vary widely. Please use [an image cropping library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45).